How to extract placeholders in a string
I have a string like:
My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\\n as a <<yourTitle>>.

How can I extract the <<placeholders>> so that eventually I get a list as:
My name is  
<<yourName>>  
and I am working in the  
<<Team Name>>  
team\\nas a  
<<yourTitle>>  

Notes:

the content between << and >> can be anything. In other words, they are not predefined.
there can be space characters between << and >> characters (like <<Team Name>>)
the string can contain newline characters \\r and/or \\n but I want them to be preserved.

I thought of using a regex in C# but couldn't succeed.

Just use Regex.Split(text, @"(<<[^<>]*(?:<(?!<)[^<]*|>(?!>)[^>]*)*>>)"). You may remove the first item if it is empty later.

A) Just splitting the string into lines as you wanted
I would go with this regex pattern:
<<(.*?)>>(\s*)

Or using named groups:
<<(?<placeholder>.*?)>>(?<spaces_after>\s*)

The replacement value, would be \n<<$1>>$2\n or respectively
\n<<${placeholder}>>${spaces_after}\n with the named groups.
Pattern details

.*? in the placeholder group is used to match anything
in an ungreedy way. This is to avoid matching >> by mistake
in a placeholder name. For example, to avoid matching
<<firstname>>, your new code is <<code>> in a string such as
Dear <<firstname>>, your new code is <<code>>. Keep it safe!.
To improve performance, one could replace .*? by [^>]*.
This will avoid the regex engine to always test the presence of
>>\s* on each step going forward. If you use .*? then you can
match a placeholder such as <<$var->property>> but the regex
engine will spend more time (85 steps instead of 33). Up to you
to see if your placeholder may contain a > character or not.

\s* in the spaces_after group is because in your output
example, you wanted to remove the space after the placeholder
and probably printed it on the line above, next to the placeholder
itself. But personally, I would not try and match these spaces
and they will just be printed on the line after the placeholder.


Test it live here: https://regex101.com/r/q3R8JB/1
An example in C#:
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<<(?<placeholder>.*?)>>(?<spaces_after>\s*)";
        string substitution = "\n<<${placeholder}>>${spaces_after}\n";
        string input = @"My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team
as a <<yourTitle>>.";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, substitution);
        Console.Write(output);
    }
}

Output (with the spaces only at the end of the lines):
My name is 
<<yourName>> 
and I am working in the 
<<Team Name>> 
team
as a 
<<yourTitle>>
.

You can execute it here for the demo:
https://www.mycompiler.io/view/61990csS2H7
B) Replacing the placeholders with values
As your question is not very precise because we don't really know
what you are trying to achieve. Typically, I imagine you would like
to replace the placeholders with some data. If this is the case,
this would be a typical usage of the Regex.Replace() method with
the use of a callback/lambda function to add the handling code for
each match. This example will look in a collection of placeholders, stored in a hash table:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Hashtable placeholders = new Hashtable();
        placeholders.Add("yourName", "James Bond");
        placeholders.Add("Team Name", "British");
        placeholders.Add("yourTitle", "secret agent");
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"<<(.*?)>>");
        
        string input = @"My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team
as a <<yourTitle>>.
If you add <<a missing placeholder>> then it will stay intact.";
        
        string output = regex.Replace(input, match => {
            if (placeholders.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value)) {
                return placeholders[match.Groups[1].Value].ToString();
            } else {
                // Nothing found, so return the original text as we won't change it.
                return match.Groups[0].Value;
            }
        });

        Console.Write(output);
    }
}

Output:
My name is James Bond and I am working in the British team
as a secret agent.
If you add <<a missing placeholder>> then it will stay intact.

Test it live here: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1T2Sg2BW2ko

You can use Regex.Split with the pattern (?=<<)|(?<=>>) to split before << and after >> by using lookarounds. This is not testing for matching pairs of << and >>.
private static readonly Regex _regex = new (@"(?=<<)|(?<=>>)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

...

string[] parts = _regex.Split(searchString);

Making the regex object a static readonly field ensures that it will be compiled and initialized only once.

If you only want to find matches, you can simply use the pattern <<.*?>>.  I assume that the placeholders will not be nested.

Note that there exists also a Regex.Replace Method. Overloads accepting a MatchEvaluator Delegate allow you to supply a value depending on the placeholder name. If you want to do this, use the pattern <<(.*?)>> with the parentheses capturing the placeholder name directly without the surrounding << and >> as Group  number 1.

"yourName>> and I am working in the <> team\n as a <<yourTitle"?

It can be solved without Regex:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program {
    static List<string> SplitByPlaceholders(string sc) {
        var result = new List<string>(); int i, j = 0;
        while ((i = sc.IndexOf("<<", j)) > -1) {
            if (i > j) result.Add(sc.Substring(j, i - j));
            j = sc.IndexOf(">>", i);
            if (j > -1) result.Add(sc.Substring(i, j - i + 2));
            else break;
            j += 2;
        }
        if (j > -1) { if (j < sc.Length) result.Add(sc.Substring(j)); }
        else result.Add(sc.Substring(i));
        return result;
    }
    static void Main() {
        foreach (var x in SplitByPlaceholders("My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\n as a <<yourTitle>>."))
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(new String('+', 60));
        foreach (var x in SplitByPlaceholders("<<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\n as a <<yourTitle>>."))
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(new String('+', 60));
        foreach (var x in SplitByPlaceholders("My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\n as a <<yourTitle."))
            Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}


My name is
<<yourName>>
and I am working in the
<<Team Name>>
team
as a
<<yourTitle>>
.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
<<yourName>>
and I am working in the
<<Team Name>>
team
as a
<<yourTitle>>
.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
My name is
<<yourName>>
and I am working in the
<<Team Name>>
team
as a
<<yourTitle.

To bypass the non-complete placeholder at the and:
    static List<string> SplitByPlaceholders(string sc) {
        var result = new List<string>(); int i, j = 0;
        while ((i = sc.IndexOf("<<", j)) > -1) {
            int k = j;
            j = sc.IndexOf(">>", i);
            if (j > -1) {
                if (i > k) result.Add(sc.Substring(k, i - k));
                result.Add(sc.Substring(i, j - i + 2));
            }
            else { i = k; break; }
            j += 2;
        }
        if (j > -1) { if (j < sc.Length) result.Add(sc.Substring(j)); }
        else result.Add(sc.Substring(i));
        return result;
    }
...
        foreach (var x in SplitByPlaceholders("yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\n as a <<yourTitle."))
            Console.WriteLine(x);

-->

yourName>> and I am working in the
<<Team Name>>
 team
 as a <<yourTitle.



You can use regex for balanced characters from this SO post. After adjustments it will look like this:
\<\<(?>\<\<(?<c>)|[^<>]+|\>\>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\>\>

It will math balanced <<...>> tokens.
THen you can use Regex.Matches and Regex.Split to get all the items you want:
var regex = new Regex(@"\<\<(?>\<\<(?<c>)|[^<>]+|\>\>(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\>\>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var searchString = "My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\n as a <<yourTitle>>.";

var matches = regex.Matches(searchString);
// It will give "<<yourName>>", "<<Team Name>>", "<<yourTitle>>"

var parts = regex.Split(searchString);
// It will give "My name is ", " and I am working in the ", " team\n as a ", "."


using System.Text;
string s = @"My name is <<yourName>> and I am working in the <<Team Name>> team\\n as a <<yourTitle>>";

// #1.
Console.WriteLine( "#1" );

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( s );
sb.Replace( " <<", Environment.NewLine + "<<" );
sb.Replace( ">> ", ">>" + Environment.NewLine );
sb.Replace( @"\\n ", Environment.NewLine );

Console.WriteLine( sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine );

// #2.
Console.WriteLine( "#2" );

sb = new StringBuilder( s );
sb.Replace( "<<", "$<<" );
sb.Replace( ">>", ">>$" );
sb.Replace( @"\\n ", Environment.NewLine );

var tokens = sb.ToString().Split( new char[] { '$' } ).ToList();

tokens.ForEach( t => Console.WriteLine( t.Trim() ) );

Console.ReadKey();

